# What is "Linking Resources" in RestEasy?

Tags: rest, resteasy

I am studying on Resful web services with RestEasy API. In [docs of API](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.17.Final/userguide/pdf/resteasy-reference-guide-en-US.pdf) at chapter 8 there is a topic called "Linking Resources." I read that chapter several times and I can not understand what it is.
What is linking resources? 
What can we do with it? 
Why do we need it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it refers to [level 3 of the Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3):

> **Hypermedia** – resources contain links to related resources and
>   collections, and also links to perform actions on the resources
>   themselves. APIs are now self-documenting and discoverable.

As to why do we need it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20336307/1791065)'s a much more details answer than I could ever write.

Of course, all these are theoretical notions - but at the same time your question doesn't seem to be too tightly coupled to the actual RestEasy implementation details.